# Why does GitHub show the same tag associated with all commits leading up to that tag?

Tags: github

A git tag is a reference to one commit in particular. In the GitHub commit view, it will show a commit as being associated with all tags that point to future commits that descend from the current one. Why?

Answer (score 0):

That commit is part of the history of that tag. It cannot be deleted, or the tag wouldn't be able to create a full history. Each commit depends on the commit before it.

The branches the commit contributes to should also be listed. Once that commit is unreachable by any tag or branch, it can be garbage collected.